# List tag inside XML. I don't understand what it does

Tags: xml, spring-mvc

This is a question related to Spring MVC. I have entries in an XML file like this.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web...DefaultAnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
          <bean class="rewardsonline.AuditInterceptor"/>
          <bean class="rewardsonline.PerformanceInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, I understand that the property called interceptors is an instance variable of the class DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping. But, I cannot make sense of the list tag. What does that indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[4.4.2.4 Collections](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements)

> In the `<list/>`, `<set/>`, `<map/>`, and `<props/>` elements, you set the properties and arguments of the Java Collection types `List`, `Set`, `Map`, and `Properties`, respectively.

Your XML fragment is constructing a `java.util.List` and injecting it ino the `interceptors` property of the `DefaultAnotationHandlerMapping` object.

Comment: Do you think this question deserves a -1?

Comment: @CodeBlue: Nope. Takes all sorts, though.

Answer (score 1):

The AbstractHandlerMapping class has a property called interceptors which is a List. The List element in the XML lists the interceptors which should be added to the interceptor list on AbstractHandlerMapping when it's initialized.

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping instead of AbstractHandlerMapping.

Comment: You're right, I'll fix that. I was referring to the class which actually declares the interceptors property.